# Compare values from two csv files, append value to text file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I have three files.  I want to compare columns with fruit in them and those that match, I want to append the matching fruit to the Append.txt file and then sort ascending.

test1.csv

```
CustID,Name,Count,Item,Date  
23,Smith,8,apples,08/12/2010  
1,Jones,8,banana,03/26/2009  
15,Miller,2,cookie dough,03/27/2009  
6,Fisher,8,oranges,06/09/2011
```

test2.csv

```
FRUIT,Amount,Aisle  
oranges,1,1  
apples,1,1  
pears,1,1
```

Append.txt

```
Fruit,Total,Aisle
cherries,1,1  
dates,2,1  
grapes,5,1  
kiwis,2,2  
peaches,2,2  
plums,1,1  
watermelon1,2
```

Code:

```
import csv

# Iterate through both  reader1 and reader2, compare common row, and append matching column data to test.txt in its matching column
with open("C:\\Test\\Append.txt", 'a') as f:
    reader1 = csv.reader(open("C:\\Test\\test1.csv", 'rb'), delimiter=',')
    row1 = reader1.next()
    reader2 = csv.reader(open("C:\\Test\\test2.csv", 'rb'), delimiter=',')
    row2 = reader2.next()
    if (row1[3] == row2[0]):
        print "code to append data from row1[0] to test.txt row[0] goes here"

f.close()
exit

print "code to sort test.txt ascending on column[0] goes here"
```

My initial script will not work. After examining I can see that the code only compares row 1 with row 1, row 2 with 2, etc.  and I really want it to compare all rows (row1 with row 1, row1 with row 2, row 2 with row 1, row 2 with row 2, etc>). After running main script, test files can be populated with no records or up to 5 records. Append file can be either empty or have hundreds of records. Using python 2.7.

I am also unsure as to how to sort the file in ascending order when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Read the two CSV files first and collect just the fruits from the rows.

Then use set intersections to find all fruit that the two files have in common, add these to the fruit from the `Append.txt` file, sort, and write all fruit back to the file.

```
import csv

# collect the fruits of both CSV files
with open('c:/Test/test1.csv', 'rb') as test1:
    reader = csv.reader(test1)
    next(reader, None)  # ignore header
    test1_fruit = set(row[3] for row in reader)
with open('c:/Test/test2.csv', 'rb') as test2:
    reader = csv.reader(test2)
    next(reader, None)  # ignore header
    test2_fruit = set(row[0] for row in reader)

# Read all the fruit from Append
with open("C:/Test/Append.txt", 'r') as append:
    fruit = set(line.strip() for line in append if line.strip())

# add all fruit that are in both test1 and test2
fruit |= test1_fruit & test2_fruit

# write out a sorted list
with open("C:/Test/Append.txt", 'w') as append:
    append.write('\n'.join(sorted(fruit)))
```

Comment: Overall it worked,. I deleted the | on line 12 and changed the 'w' to 'a' on line 15 otherwise it overwrote the existing data inside the Append.txt file. Anyway to put a newline at the end of the Append file? To those newbies (like me) don't forget to import csv. Yahoo. Thanks.

Comment: @user12059: Right, I interpreted your question slightly differently. If you remove the `|` then you did not care about the fruit *already* listed in `Append.txt`, so I removed reading that file altogether. Added the extra newline for you.

Comment: Perfect. It now makes sense to me that it would be nested just inside the last bracket. Your my new BFF of the day. :-)

Comment: Martijn Pieters I just noticed a snag. It only sorts the appended data, not the entire file. The appended data needs to be integrated into the entire list alphabetically.

Comment: @user12059: That was what my original version did. I'll roll that part back. That is why you needed the `|=` inplace `or` as well, to merge the fruit from the CSV files into the fruit list from the text file.

Comment: But when I leave the |= in I get the following: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |= 'list' and 'set". (note. I am using python 2.7. Arcgis limitation) Also, why when the field names that are compared to each other are the same name for both files, does it append the actual field name from test1 as well as the matching records? Is it because it does not skip the header info?

Comment: Ah, that is my mistake. Corrected by creating a set when reading. It now also skips the header.

Comment: Almost there. Anyway to skip the header when sorting?

Comment: What header? Append.txt has no header in you example. The CSV file headers are ignored.

Comment: You're right. I omitted the header info. (It is still in dbf format-still to be converted. I hand typed it in notepad to give you an idea of what the file looked liked. I should have known to include the headers. It actually has three headers, just like test2.) I try to be thorough when posting but always manage to miss some important detail or another. I'm sorry. I am sure that as I use the forums more frequently, I will get better at being precise in my questions.

Comment: In this case you'd have to read those header lines separately, right before reading the Append fruit lines into the set, then write them out again right before writing the sorted fruit lines. Hint: use `next()` to read one line from the file.... :-)

Comment: Got the code to work the way I want. I will post my code tomorrow. I am an hour late getting home to the kids and they're crying for their supper. Thanks again. I learned a lot.